# folder structure for c++ programming

Tags: c++, directory-structure

I am using visual studios. Below is my current project folder structure.
 [image: Folder Structure]

I am actually practicing all codes in a book. So, i want to create a folder for each chapter and write each exercise in a separate `.cpp` file. But, i am not sure if creating folders under `"source files"` folder is the correct thing to do. Should i create a folder inside of Source files or outside? what's the standard way of doing it?

Comment: Yes use `Source Files`

Comment: @smac89, just wondering, how can i have multiple cpp files, each having its own main method? since each file is a separate exercise, should i just comment main function of other programs when running?

Comment: you can make separate projects for that

Comment: @kmdreko, But, making separate project will split my codes. I wanted to put them under one solution. Can i make multiple projects in one solution?

Comment: Yup. Just right click the solution and click add -> New Project. It will bring up a wizard to add a new project to your solution.

Comment: I have never used VS, but I don't see why you can't just have each main file in the same directory then choose which one to run in VS. Otherwise, you may need to make a new project for each exercise

Comment: There's no such as correct way for folder structure, you will add more folders or remove some depend on your project. but in general, You should have at least two folder structure  one called header files for .h files and the other is source file for .cpp files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them to separate projects. To do that, simply right-click the solution, select Add -> New Project... That will bring up a wizard to make a new project in your solution. Then, you can have another main inside that project.